# refresh page after upload file to server

Tags: javascript, fetch

I would like that after uploading the image to the servers the page is refreshed with a reload as I implement it thanks

```
  <code>function imagenes()
{
let fd = new FormData();
fd.append("archivo",
document.getElementById("archivo").files\[0\]);
fetch('subir_archivo.php',
{ method: 'POST', body: fd })
.then(response => response.json() )
}</code>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can react on the promise returned by `fetch`. If the server gives a successful response, your code enters the `.then()` block of the promise where you can trigger the [page reload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload). You might also think about error handling for the case that the upload fails.

```
function images() {
    let fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("archivo", document.getElementById("archivo").files\[0\]);
    fetch('subir_archivo.php', { method: 'POST', body: fd }).then(response => {
        response.json();
        window.location.reload(); // <-- page reload
    });
}
```